# A WritableImage to a BufferImage to a File on lthe computer - something is missing

Tags: image-processing, javafx

s

```
 public void copy(WritableImage temp) throws IOException {
        BufferedImage fromFXImage = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(temp, null);      
        File outputfile = new File("File: src/main/images/test.jpg");
        ImageIO.write(fromFXImage, "jpg", outputfile);

    }
```

I am trying to snapshot a node in Javafx and wanted to create this small method to actually export it as an image file on my computer. This method is not giving me errors but is not making any images appear either. What am I missing here?

Comment: Check 1. where that file ends up being (`System.out.println(outputFile.toURI())`) and 2. whether `ImageIO.write(...)` returns `true` or `false`. What happens to any exception thrown (i.e. where are you calling `copy()` from, and do you wrap the call in a `try` with a corresponding `catch`)?

Comment: [mcve] please ..